# Load File in GUI GUIDE to Read 2 Columns in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I've been at this for 3 hours -- so I need help.

I have a button on MATLAB's GUI GUIDE to load a text file to store 2
columns of data as `x` and `y`.

So `x = [12, 12, 23];`

textfile A is:

```
  12 23
  12 32
  23 32
```

The code that is in the GUI GUIDE is under the `pushbutton` load_file as follows:

```
filename = uigetfile('*.txt')
loaddata = fullfile(pathname,filename)
load(loaddata)
A = filename(:,1)
B = filename(:,2)
handles.input1 = A;
handles.input2 = B;
axes(handles.axes1)
plot(handles.input1,handles,imput2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` will load a text file, but it won't assign the contents to anything unless you explicitly specify an output.

```
%# load xy data from file
xy = load(loaddata,'-ascii')
%# assign columns to A and B, respectively
%# (why not x,y)?
A = xy(:,1)
B = xy(:,2)
```

The `-ascii` option of load is not necessary, but guarantees that the file is loaded as text, and will help you remember later that the data is supposed to be a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you might want to post your error message to make sure I'm reporting on the right problem, but I can see one problem right off:

the lines:

```
A = filename(:,1)
B = filename(:,2)
```

are only retrieving a string naming the file, not the actual data.  So first, you have to know the name of the data that is being loaded, then change the load line to:

```
data = load(loaddata,'-ascii')
```

and now:

```
A = data(:,1)
B = data(:,2)
```

Comment: This answer would be correct if the file `loaddata` was a .mat-file. Unfortunately, it isn't.